# IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled VBNET

Tags: vb.net

I have a form that retrieves the CurrentYear`year_now` and NextYear`year_next` from the database. It gives me the error 'IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled' bcoz I think there is no row to be retrieved. And I wanted to do is, even though there's no data from the table, I can still load the forms and give me a null value to be displayed. I tried everything I know to make it work but I cant resolve the problem. Is there anyway to recode this.

```
 Sub LoadSchoolYear()
    Dim conn1 As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; userid=root; password=root; database=uecp_cens")
    Dim dAdapter1 As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT year_now, year_next FROM uecp_cens.tblschoolyear", conn1)
    Dim dTable1 As New DataSet
    Try
        dAdapter1.Fill(dTable1, "uecp_cens")
        lblYearNow.Text = dTable1.Tables("uecp_cens").Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
        lblYearNext.Text = dTable1.Tables("uecp_cens").Rows(0).Item(1).ToString
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn1.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you already know the cause of the problem (no rows in the datatable), you should easily fix it yourself (use a simple `If` statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no row in the table as you've mentioned you get that error. So check `Rows.Count`:

```
Dim yearNow As String = Nothing
Dim yearNext As String = Nothing
If dTable1.Tables("uecp_cens").Rows.Count > 0 Then 
    yearNow = dTable1.Tables("uecp_cens").Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()
    yearNext = dTable1.Tables("uecp_cens").Rows(0).Item(1).ToString()
End If
lblYearNow.Text = yearNow
lblYearNext.Text = yearNext
```

If instead the field is `NULL` in the DB it is `DBNull.Value` and you get an exception if you use `Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()`. Then use `DataRow.IsNull` to check it:

```
If dTable1.Tables("uecp_cens").Rows.Count > 0 Then 
    Dim row = dTable1.Tables("uecp_cens").Rows(0)
    yearNow = If(row.IsNull(0), Nothing,  row.Item(0).ToString())
    yearNext = If(row.IsNull(1), Nothing,  row.Item(1).ToString())
End If
```